# How to use UTF-8 characters in dygraph title in R

Tags: r, utf-8, dygraphs

Using Rstudio [Windows8], when I use the dygraph function to plot a time series, I have a problem when trying to use UTF-8 characters in the main title.

```
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(AirPassengers, main = "Título")
```

This results in a title: "T?tulo"

I have tried to convert "Título" to the utf-8 enconding, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your locale settings support the character that you want to use, and that the file is saved with the right encoding. Saving as UTF-8 worked for me.

I was able to replicate your situation in Windows 7 and tried a bunch of things. Embedded in Rmarkdown, here is a minimal working example.

````
```{r}
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","German")
#note that windows locale names are different from unix & mac, usually
#the name of nationality works here.
#also works with "Faroese", "Hungarian", and others who have this letter.
#the locale has to be set in a preceding block to take effect.
```

```{r}
Encoding("Título")
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(AirPassengers, main = "Título")
```
````

You can try out the encoding given to the title to have with `Encoding()`. Languages like Faroese, Hungarian, and German encode "Título" as latin or unknown, both of which seem to cause no problems for dygraph's javascript. UTF-8 wrote it as `<U+00ED>` which was a problem for the javascript, as well as some, but not all other functions. With a matching locale, converting to utf-8 as @Michele recommended has the same result.

Also, if you don't have the title in many places, it is possible to just manually find and replace the title in the html/javascript file that is made. The problem occurs on conversion, but if the file is already made, the title variable can be successfully changed. The letter still has a question mark in Rstudio "Viewer" output, but I recommend making the entire file for javascript regularly, as I've seen other functions malfunction in the viewer window.

Answer (score 3):

You can use enc2utf8.

```
dygraph(AirPassengers, main = enc2utf8("Título"))
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  The problem persists. I use windows

Comment: I ran the code on a Mac, so it's possible that it doesn't work on Windows. However, the post didn't specify the operating system.