# R barplot with German encoding

Tags: r, encoding, bar-chart

My R script uses the R visialization library barplot. The problem is, that I need German characters such as äöü in the labeling.

I am working with the Eclipse plugiin StatET and on a 64-bit-Windows system. I tried to set up the correct encoding by Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale="German_Germany"); 
Tests with print("äöü") gives the correct result, but when integrating those "Umlauts" in the barplot, it the graph shows the labeling with characters such as Ã¤.

```
plot <- barplot(as.matrix(comp), beside=TRUE, ylim = c(0,100), main="äöü", legend.text = TRUE);
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

**EDIT**

The result for Sys.getlocale('LC_CTYPE') is:

[1] "German_Germany.1252"

Comment: I've had moderate success getting [unicode](http://character-code.com/german-html-codes.php) characters to show up in R. Maybe try those?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the letters properly without alteration. Maybe try:

```
plot <- barplot(df, main= enc2utf8("äöü"), legend.text = TRUE);
```

As proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973479/how-to-use-utf-8-characters-in-dygraph-title-in-r/28973880#28973880).

Comment: I am getting the same result when using the convert function enc2utf8()..this seems to be a general windows problem.

Comment: Can you show the result of :   Sys.getlocale('LC_CTYPE')

Comment: It might be the environment. I don't know about Eclipse. In RStudio they explain: "If you call Sys.setlocale with "LC_CTYPE" or "LC_ALL" to change the system locale while RStudio is running, you may run into some minor issues as RStudio assumes the system encoding doesn't change. If you are on Windows, we recommend you only call Sys.setlocale in .Rprofile."

Comment: Maybe investigate other function to plot your graph, like ggplot2, givs... Have also a look at PostScript Graphics it seems you can export plots as file of a specific encoding: http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=grDevices/man/postscript.Rd&d=R_rel

Comment: #Here are some functions related to Encoding you might want to try:
    getOption("encoding") #Your native encoding should be ISO-8859-1
    
    Encoding(x)   #Reveals the encoding of the object
    
    enc2utf8(x)   #Convert a vector to UTF-8
    enc2native(x) #Convert a vector to native encoding
    xx <- iconv(x, "latin1", "UTF-8") #Change and encoding from... to...
    
    #Play with "Umlauts"
    B <- "\x9a\x8a\x9f\x85\x80\x86" #
    Encoding(B)
    iconv(B, to="UTF-8") 
    iconv("öäüÖÄÜ", to="MAC")

Comment: I will give ggplot2 a try..in the meantime I try to avoid those Umlauts.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Eclipse or 64-bit Windows, but since the question in the OP is phrased more generally: As far as I understand it, at least for exporting a plot as pdf, it is generally sufficient to set the correct locale (as you have) and putting the characters in [octal representation](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html) (`\344\366\374`). E.g,

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "german")
plot <- barplot(as.matrix(comp), beside=TRUE, ylim = c(0,100), main="\344\366\374\337", legend.text = TRUE)
```